# Using wildcard file names in asp.net core bundle.config using BundlerMinifier

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, bundling-and-minification

I am using the [BundlerMinifier](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier) nuget package for bundling in ASP.Net Core 2.0. While it is working fine, I was not sure how I would have versioning for the js files.

For example, In ASP.Net MVC I used to do something like :

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Script1")
        .Include("~/Scripts/script1-{version}.js"));
```

And changing the file version would not mean I have to change in all the files using it as the output minified file remained the same.

However, In Core I am having to do something like :

```
{
"outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/script-1.0.0.min.js",
"inputFiles": [ "wwwroot/js/script-1.0.0.js" ]
}
```

So everytime I change the file version, I will have to change the output file name as well and that would mean having to change in all views which use the script file.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 4):

```
"inputFiles": ["wwwroot/**/*(*.css|!(*.min.css))"]
```

[From Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)